# How to properly fix random seed in pytorch-forecasting with TFT model?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

Pytorch-forecasting is a library for time series forecasting.
I wonder how to fix seed to get the reproducibility of my experiments.
Right now I'm using this function before the start of the training.

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
pl.seed_everything(42)
```

However, it doesn't work. It is caused by dropout because when I set dropout = 0 it had worked.

```
    # configure network and trainer
pl.seed_everything(42)
trainer = pl.Trainer(
    deterministic=True,
    gpus=[0],
    gradient_clip_val=0.1,
)


tft = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate=0.03,
    hidden_size=128,
    attention_head_size=2,
    dropout=0.3,  
    hidden_continuous_size=32,  
    output_size=7,  
    loss=QuantileLoss(),
    reduce_on_plateau_patience=4,
)

trainer.fit(
    tft,
    train_dataloader=train_dataloader,
    val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
)
```

So, how do I do to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you pls also share what PL versions have you been using? Thx